# #memsql - REPLACE does not work on columnstore tables

Tags: singlestore

Does REPLACE work with columnstore tables in #memsql ? 
The Memsql documentation does not mention about this but I am not able to replace a record in a columnstore.  IS there any way to implement REPLACE in a columnstore ?

Thanks 
zebb

Answer (score 1):

REPLACE is only useful with unique keys, otherwise it is just equivalent to INSERT, and columnstore tables do not support unique keys.

There isn't a good way to implement it efficiently in the columnstore, since columnstores are generally not intended to perform well for single-row updates. See http://docs.memsql.com/docs/columnstore.

One way you can implement it (not very efficiently) is with multistatement transactions. Run a select to see whether a matching row is already present, if so run an update, otherwise run an insert.

E.g. say we have

```
create table c(i int, a int, key using clustered columnstore(i));
```

We can do

```
memsql> begin;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

memsql> select count(*) from c where i = 4;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

memsql> insert into c values (4, 4);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

memsql> commit;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

in the case where there is no match, and

```
memsql> begin;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

memsql> select count(*) from c where i = 4;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        1 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

memsql> update c set a = 4 where i = 4;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

memsql> commit;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

in the case where there is a match.